# PC_in and PC_out values after code execution in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am currently studying for my computer architecture class and came across this exercise[image: Mips code and memory addresses]

The question was: "What is the PC_In value and what the PC_Out value when sub is executed"

I would suppose that input would be 0x10000004 and output would be 0x10000008,but apparently it is the other way round. Could someone explain this? Thanks

Comment: `sub` can't observe PC, so in terms of the pure MIPS ISA on paper, there's no meaningful answer.  Hardware can do whatever it likes.  Only `j` and `b` instructions, (and MIPS326r `addiupc`), actually read (and write) PC; their semantics are defined in the ISA, e.g. branches are relative to the end of the instruction.  If you're talking about some specific implementation of MIPS, which one?

Comment: It is a matter of terminology, and these terms are not universal, which makes it hard for us to do anything but (educated) guessing.  You should consult your coursework, maybe look for labels on a block diagram they're using.

Comment: when sub is "executed" depends on the implementation (pipeline depth, stages).  So there is not enough information here to know where the pc is during or after "execution".  and of course the definition of pc pc_in, pc_out (and other program counters in the design) are implementation specific.

Comment: For example I would expect pc_in to be 0x10000010 and pc_out to be 0x1000000C. or even the 0x10000014 and 0x10000010 depending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that PC_in is the value coming into the program counter for the next cycle, and PC_out is the output of the program counter. This means that PC_out hold the address of the current instruction (0x10000004) while PC_in holds the value to be written in the program counter, the address of the next instruction (0x10000008)